# Arithmetic operations not working in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two xsl variables values of they are like this

```
  <xsl:value-of select="$singleprice"/> // value= 1,56
  <xsl:value-of select="$asd"/>  //value=25
```

And I am making a multiplication like this

```
 <xsl:value-of select="$asd * $singleprice"/>
```

everything looks okay to me ,but it alwasys returns `NAN`
Can any one point out what is I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath/XSLT 1.0 number format is double precision floating *point* numbers so your input needs to be in the format `1.26`, not `1,26`.